# Populate a form after submit with jQuery and ajax from

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a basic HTML form and want to preform a lookup with Ajax via a PHP file after filling in the first field, looking in an external feed for the values of the two second fields.

```
<form method="post" action="#"> 
 <input name="number" type="text" id="number" value="" />
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" />
 <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" />
 <button type"submit">
</form>
```

After filling in the first field (number), I want to do an Ajax call to a PHP file (submitting the filled in value) and look for the values of the two other fields (name and email). After the lookup fill in the found values in this form, user can edit if wanted and then submit.

The PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php 
  $number = $_GET["number"];
  $url = "http://api.domain.com/lookup/$number";
  $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
?>
```

And will give a json response like this

```
{
    "name": "jacob",
    "email": "jacob@domain.com"
}
```

Now I need jQuery to complete this task (call the PHP script and populate the other form fields) and that's where I got stuck. Ideas?

Comment: what did you try? Did you actually try a "onchange" event on your number field to do your check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**AJAX**

Put this code between `<head>` and `</head>` tags of your form page and remember to call jquery framework.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#number" ).keyup(function() {
    numberval = $('#number').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "PHP-FILE.php", // replace 'PHP-FILE.php with your php file
        data: {number: numberval},
        success: function(data) {
           $('#name').val(data["name"]);
           $("#email").val(data["email"]);
        },
        error : function(){
           alert('Some error occurred!');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**FORM**

```
<form method="post" action="#"> 
 <input name="number" type="text" id="number" value="" />
 <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" />
 <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" />
 <button type"submit">
</form>
```

Comment: ajaxCall is called only when focusout here... quick solution but not 100% effective... (Fill 2nd & 3rd fields 1st, then number and do not get out but just post form with enter & see)

Comment: It will work for now, maybe it's better to add an extra button as well to retrieve the data in stead of onchange. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dennis I added a keyup() binding so you don't need any extra button and all works well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$.post('localhost/your_url.php',{number:$("#number").val()}, function(data,status) {
    if(status=='success'){
        var  obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $("#name").val(obj.name);
        $("#email").val(obj.email);
    }else{
        //fail
    }
});
```

cause the script above is use post please change php script to _POST
or do you have any need why using _get ?

Comment: there is `var  obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Dennis, this event will be triggered when the number field loses focus, for example when the user clicks on another form element. You could use a different event like [form submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) or [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twittomyates/2pps74h5/) for a demo.

**AJAX**

```
$('#number').focusout(function() {

    var url = "http://api.domain.com/lookup/" + this.value;

    $.get( url, function( data ) {

        console.log(data);

        $("#name").val( data.name );
        $("#email").val( data.email );

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, need some more information. What do you mean with "after filling in the first field"?

The 2 next fields are disabled until a "number" is written in the 1st field? 
the 2 next fields are available and have to work like the 1st one? (doing a data check on value change?)

Sounds like you have to use an event handler anyway, like this with jquery :

```
$(document).on('change keyup keypress','#number',function(){
    //Do whatever you want with $(this).val() is the field current value;
});
```

check this example : http://jsfiddle.net/w12bbzmh/5/

About your $ajax, it's easy to do it with jquery, you can do it the way Rifai told, or like this (which is, to me, clearer)

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',//OR GET
    url : '..',
    data : {'name':'value','name1':'value1',...},
    async : true or false,
    cache : false,
    success : function(response){
        //handle your response (success)
        //here you get your result, do whatever you need to do here
    },
    error : function(response){
        //handle your response error
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!